# How to set fontsize of axis label with LaTex symbol on matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In matplotlib, how can I change the font size of a latex symbol?

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# get x and y from file

plt.plot(x, y,  linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$ (distance weighted)', fontsize='large')
plt.ylabel('AUC')
plt.show()
```

But I get the following graph:

[image]

Notice that the $\alpha$ is still small.

Comment: I do not think you can just increase the letter alpha: you can increase the whole label, but this is not what you want. Consider removing alpha from title and adding it in separate text field with the size you like: 

<code>plt.text(0.5,-0.1,r'$\alpha$', fontsize=40)</code>

Comment: I've never understood why the latex fonts are smaller than the normal fonts in matplotlib, but you could write the whole label in latex, e.g. `r'$\alpha\/\mathsf{(distance\/weighted)}$'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the size of the fonts set the desired value to fontsize. One way to mitigate the difference between the "normal" font and the "latex" one is by using \mathrm. The example below shows the behaviour of doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

for i, j in zip(np.arange(4), [10,15,20,30]):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
    ax.plot(x, y,  linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{\alpha \ (distance \ weighted)}$', fontsize=j)
    ax.set_ylabel('AUC')
plt.show()
```

[image]